# The Android SDK Folder can no longer reside in the Applications folder - it DOESN'T?

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm getting the above error when trying to upgrade Android Studio even though I have already moved the SDK to my home folder.  It DOES NOT exist in the Applications folder.  I have tried re-starting the machine (Mac) and also gone into the project settings of all of my projects to make sure they are correctly pointing to the SDK in my home folder.  But I still get this error.

Does anyone know why Android Studio thinks there is still an SDK in my Applications folder even though there isn't ?

Comment: I managed to get round this, only by uninstalling and re-installing Android Studio.

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall and re-install Android Studio.

Answer (score 0):

It's not about where you move the SDK - it's about where you tell Android Studio to *look* forthe SDK.

Go into your settings and change the path to the SDK.

Answer (score 0):

I still got this error even if I have android SDK elsewhere.

The problem is that I left the folder sdk inside android folder even if it is empty and even id my android-sdk is not pointing to that folder.

I just deleted that empty sdk folder inside android and clicked on retry... it worked.